# A servlet that used to work and now it magically doesn't

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I haven't touched this project in a long time, but I could swear it worked the last time I tried it. Now, of course, it doesn't.

It's a java servlet that takes some java code, compiles it and returns some html with the results (either "compile successful" or "compile error at line xxx"). It's built with only 2 classes: "Compiler" that extends from HttpServlet, and "JavaObjectFromString" that extends from SimpleJavaFileObject.

Class JavaObjectFromString looks like this:

```
package servlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;

public class JavaObjectFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject{

    private String contents;
    private String name;

    public JavaObjectDesdeString(String className, String cont){
        super(URI.create(className.replace('.', '/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
        contents=cont);
        name=className);
    }

    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) throws IOException {
        return contents;
    }
}
```

Class Compiler looks like this:

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler.CompilationTask;


@WebServlet("/compiler")
public class Compiler extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String code = request.getParameter("usercodefromhtml").toString();
        String results = this.compileCode(code);
        sb.append("<html><body bgcolor=pink text=black>");
        sb.append("<h1 align=center>" + results + "</h1>");
        sb.append("<body></html>");
        out.println(sb);
    }



    private String compileCode(String codeToCompile){
        String results = null;

        /*Creating dynamic java source code file object*/
        SimpleJavaFileObject fileObject = new JavaObjectFromString ("userclass", codeToCompile);
        JavaFileObject javaFileObjects[] = new JavaFileObject[]{fileObject} ;

        /*Instantiating the java compiler*/
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

        /*Create a diagnostic controller, which holds the compilation problems*/
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

        /*get a standard file manager from compiler, this file manager helps us to customize how a compiler reads and writes to files*/
        StandardJavaFileManager stdFileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);

        /* Prepare a list of compilation units (java source code file objects) to input to compilation task*/
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(javaFileObjects);

        /*Prepare any compilation options to be used during compilation
        //In this example, we are asking the compiler to place the output files under bin folder.*/
        String[] compileOptions = new String[]{"-d", "c:"} ;
        Iterable<String> compilationOptions = Arrays.asList(compileOptions);

        /*Create a compilation task from compiler by passing in the required input objects prepared above*/
        CompilationTask compilerTask = compiler.getTask(null, stdFileManager, diagnostics, compilationOptions, null, compilationUnits) ;
        /*Perform the compilation by calling the call method on compilerTask object.*/
        boolean status = compilerTask.call();
        /*On compilation failure, we can use the diagnostic collector to read the error messages and log them in specific format.*/
        if (!status){//If compilation error occurs
            /*Iterate through each compilation problem and print it*/
            for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()){
                results = "Error en la línea "+diagnostic.getLineNumber();
            }
        }
        else
            results = "Compilación exitosa";

        /*Finally close the fileManager instance to flush out anything that is there in the buffer.*/
        try {
            stdFileManager.close() ;//Close the file manager
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return results;
    }   
}
```

I compiled those two into .class files in an older Eclipse version (I haven't re-compiled since then).

I also have this form in an html file, that I suppose calls the servlet and passes it the "usercodefromhtml" parameter with the code the user writes in that textarea:

```
<form action="compiler" method="post">
    <textarea rows="18" cols="70" name="usercodefromhtml"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

(I also tried "/compiler" and "Compiler" as the action value, but no luck).

This is how I installed and configured tomcat:

1. I downloaded de 64 bit windows version from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi
2. I added two environment variables:
   JAVA_HOME -> path to JDK (in my case it's C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40)
   CATALINA_HOME -> path to tomcat (in my case it's C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.53)
3. I edited environment Path and added %JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin. I then ran configtest.bat from tomcat and it threw no errors.
4. In the webapps folder in tomcat, I created a folder for my project, where I placed my html containing the form code (as shown above).
5. In the project folder inside "webapps", I created a WEB-INF folder where I placed the web.xml and a "classes" folder with a subfolder named "servlet" containing the 2 compiled classes (.class files) I showed above.

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Compiler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.Compiler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Compiler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Compiler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then, from cmd I ran startup.bat from tomcat folder. I opened the html file in my browser, entered some random code in the textarea and pressed the submit button. Nothing.
No class file (as a result of compilation task) is created in c: either.

I believe the two classes were working correctly the last time I tested them, so I'm more inclined to think this is a configuration problem... But where?
Thanks!

Comment: you never define *"doesn't work"*

Comment: Sorry Jarrod, I only said "nothing" because it literally does nothing. Whenever I click on the "submit" button nothing happens. I checked my C:\ folder to see if a compiled .class had been dropped there, but nope. I don't even know if the servlet is being called, as I get no feedback at all.

Comment: I created the servlet a long while ago (older version of Eclipse and older version of java JDK). I remember changing the eclipse compiler from JRE to JDK when I created the project. Could it be that since I have a newer java version now something is not matching?

Answer (score 0):

No. 5 is your problem.

You need to put your classes and web.xml in to the webapps directory, next to your html file.

So, it should look like:

```
$tomcat/webapps/yourapp
           |
           +-----> your.html
           +-----> WEB-INF
                      |
                      +-----> web.xml
                      +-----> classes
                                 |
                                 +----> servlet
                                           |
                                           +-----> Compiler.class
```

Then it should work for you.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I explained it the wrong way, but that's how I'm doing it. Still no luck :(